# Suspend to ram with process in state 'D'

Tags: suspend

`s2ram` does not work. It seems to complain about 2 tasks refusing to freeze:

```
Aug  7 15:47:42 aspire kernel: [205691.318896] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug  7 15:47:42 aspire kernel: [205691.336925] Filesystems sync: 0.018 seconds
Aug  7 15:48:02 aspire kernel: [205691.337381] Freezing user space processes ... 
Aug  7 15:48:02 aspire kernel: [205711.338132] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.001 seconds (2 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
Aug  7 15:48:02 aspire kernel: [205711.338532] sshd            D    0 337591      1 0x80004004
```

So the first task seems to be 337591. The second seems to be 337909:

```bsh
$ ps -o cmd,stat -p  337591
CMD                         STAT
[sshd]                      Ds
$ ps -o cmd,stat -p  337909
CMD                         STAT
[sshd]                      D
```

D indicates uninterruptible sleep. So I cannot kill the processes (does the OOM killer respect that?).

Is there a way I can say: I don't care - please suspend anyway? Maybe something similar to `umount -l`.

These two processes are not important to me. I can live with them being stuck forever or be killed.